# PHP - Large Array merging by key content

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm currently working on a PHP project in which I need to merge 5 large arrays of arrays (around 16000 entries each) by a specific key value. With this I mean each array includes about 16000 entries, each being an array with key => value format, and I intend to merge all these arrays where the value for a given key matches. For example:

I have:

```
 arr1=[[id=>1,name=>john,surname=>doe],[id=>2,name=>katy,surname=>johnson]];
arr2=[[id=>2,age=>23,adress=>something][id=>1,age=>43,adress=>something else]];
arr3=[[id=>1,employee_number=1234],[id=>3,employee_number=2345],[id=>2,emplyee_number=>6523]];
```

And plan to obtain:

```
arr=[[id=>1,name=>john,surname=>doe,age=43,adress=>something else],[id=>2,name=>katy,surname=>johnson,age=>23,adress=>something]];
```

My first attempt was to loop through every array using for loops and join the arrays when the given value for the id key was matched, but this proved highly inefficient for such a big number of entries (16000 for each array). Can someone suggest any better options to accomplish the given task?

Edit:

Even though the example has generic arrays names (arr1,arr2) the code I tried to implement was this, with the referred 5 arrays and looping through each to compare and tried to merge by the sku key value.

```
for($i=0;$i < sizeof($received_products); $i++){        
  for($j=0; $j < sizeof($received_descriptions); $j++){
    for($k=0; $k < sizeof($received_multimedia); $k++){
      for($l=0; $l < sizeof($received_stocks); $l++){
        for($m=0; $m < sizeof($received_prices); $m++){
          if(strcmp(strcmp($received_products[$i]['sku'],$received_descriptions[$j]['sku'])&&strcmp($received_multimedia[$k]['sku'],$received_stocks[$l]['sku']),$received_prices[$m]['sku'])==0){
              $all_products[$i]=array_merge($received_products[$i],$received_descriptions[$j],$received_multimedia[$k],$received_stocks[$l],$received_prices[$m]);
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: 48 thousand iterations really isn't all that much. PHP should be able to chew through it rather quickly. Can you show the code you have?

Comment: Yes, had to edit the post due to caracter limit. Even though i only exemplified with 3 arrays, i refered 5, and as i am using nested for loops woudn't the correct number of iterations be, 16000^5, as for each element in the first loop there are 16000 possibilities to check in the next loop and so on and so forth??

Comment: That's what I assumed you were doing. But why nested loops? If all you're looking to do is to merge all these arrays, you can loop each of them individually and build a new resulting array.

Comment: I'am sorry got me confused there. How can i ensure they are all merged by the given key, if they are not ordered and some of them might be missing a few entries (probably should have mentioned)?

Comment: What does it matter if they're ordered or not? Use the id as the key of the resulting array for easy access. Then you just check if the key exists; if it does, merge and if it doesn't, add new element.

Comment: ohh i see, great thinking, thx for the help!!!

Comment: You're welcome. And you have a concrete implementation of that logic in Rob's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with two nested loops:

```
<?php
$arr1 = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'john', 'surname' => 'doe'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'katy', 'surname' => 'johnson']];
$arr2 = [['id' => 2, 'age' => 23, 'address' => 'something'], ['id' => 1, 'age' => 43, 'address' => 'something else']];
$arr3 = [['id' => 1, 'employee_number' => 1234], ['id' => 3, 'employee_number' => 2345], ['id' => 2, 'emplyee_number' => 6523]];

$buffer = [];

// For each of the records sets...
foreach ([$arr1, $arr2, $arr3] as $currRecordSet)
{
    // Loop through the records...
    foreach ($currRecordSet as $currRecord)
    {
        // If we do not have an entry in our buffer for ths ID yet, create one
        $currKey = '_' . $currRecord['id'];
        if (!array_key_exists($currKey, $buffer))
        {
            $buffer[$currKey] = [];
        }

        // Merge this record with the values in the buffer
        $buffer[$currKey] = array_merge($buffer[$currKey], $currRecord);
    }
}

// Get the bare array of combined entries without our ugly buffer keys
$combinedRecords = array_values($buffer);
print_r($combinedRecords);
```